# else statement proceeds to execute even if statements are encountered

Tags: java, if-statement

I am working in Java and I have come across a trouble in my code where I have multiple `if` statements and one `else`. Despite the if statements being true, the else statements still execute. I've been encountering this all day and I can't seem to find the error. If anyone can help

```
private void confirmActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

    if(lname1.getText().equals("")){
         lname_ver1.setText("Field is empty!");

     }
    if (mname1.getText().equals("")){
        mname_ver1.setText("Field is empty!");

    }
    if(fname1.getText().equals("")){
       fname_ver.setText("Field is empty!");

    }
     if(s_age.getSelectedIndex()== 0){
     age_ver.setText("Field is empty!");
    }
    if(!female_button.isSelected()&& !male_button.isSelected()){
    gender_ver1.setText("Select gender!");
    }
    if(month.getSelectedIndex()==0 && day.getSelectedIndex()==0 && year.getSelectedIndex()==0){
            birth_ver1.setText("Field is empty!");
            }

    if (s_num.getText().equals("")){
          num_ver.setText("Field is empty!"); 

    }


     if(!email.getText().matches("\"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[@]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")){
       email_ver1.setText("Invalid email!");
     }
     if(email.getText().equals("")){
        email_ver1.setText("Field is empty!");

     if(fathers_name.getText().equals("")){
        father_ver1.setText("Field is empty!")
    }
     if(mothers_name.getText().equals("")){
     mother_ver1.setText("Field is empty!");   
    }
     if(parent_no.getText().equals("")){
     no_verify1.setText("Field is empty!");  
     }
     if(parent_no.getText().contains("[a-zA-Z]")){
         no_verify1.setText("Field is empty!");
     }

     if (s_nat.getText().equals("")){
      nat_ver.setText("Field is empty!");
     }
     if(!single.isSelected() && married.isSelected()){
            nat_ver.setText("Select status!!");
     }



   else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SUCCESS", "INFO    ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        dispose();
        Schedule sched = new Schedule();
        sched.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        sched.setResizable(false);
        sched.setVisible(true);
    }`
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding `if else` statements. `else` executes after last `if` be `false`. It doesn't matter how many `if` before last `if` be `true`. Are you looking for `if () {} else if () {}` ?

Comment: In addition you could use `return;` statement in every `if` block to don't go further.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. As Masoud already said, your `else` only depends on the `if` directly preceeding it. Also please check the state of your caps-lock key.

Comment: I think it would be a helpful practice to provide `if`, `if-else` and `else` in the order of requirements so that some conditions which are satisfied by multiple `if`'s won't be triggered too. Also, we can neglect an `else` in `if`, `if-else` format which might satisfy the requirements of the code above.

Comment: wouldn't it affect the statements though? because iv'e tried using if... else if... else. and what it does is check the first IF STATEMENT only, and then if the first is false, proceeds to the next, and so on. but i want to check all of the statements all at once, once the confirmAction is performed. is there a solution for that?

Comment: Do you want the code in the else block to be called if any of the if statements are false?

Comment: no, i want it to execute only if all if statements are false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the if statements are independent from each other. The else belongs only to the last if statement. It will be executed if single or married have been selected. The other conditions do not matter.

I think, your intention is evaluating user inputs. You want to put an error message to each invalid input and proceed only if everything is valid. If this is what you wanted, there is a simple solution for it:

```
private void confirmActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  boolean valid = true;

  if (lname1.getText().equals("")) {
    lname_ver1.setText("Field is empty!");
    valid = false;
  }
  if (mname1.getText().equals("")) {
    mname_ver1.setText("Field is empty!");
    valid = false;
  }
  ...
  if (valid) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SUCCESS", "INFO    ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    dispose();
    Schedule sched = new Schedule();
    sched.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    sched.setResizable(false);
    sched.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

And keep you parantheses balanced, look at the statement `if(email.getText().equals("")){`.

Comment: thankyou for this good sir. i found this solution to solve the problem.

Comment: and if may i ask? what is the problem with that statement you are saying? isnt it balance? since im not getting any errors

Comment: I think there is a missing closing curly bracket for the if statement indicated. But maybe, it is just a typo when you copied the code for your question.

Answer (score 0):

1)Please verify whether braces opening and closing is perfectly matching your requirements.
    2)If else format....
    if{}
    else if{}
    else if{}
    else{} 
     In this format if any of the condition before else works, then else wont execute, but your case is little different like

```
if{}
if{}
if{}
if{}
.
.
.
.
if{}  ----//last if
else{}

so in this case, else is applicable only for the last if, so when last if fails, it goes for else, and the if conditions which are mentioned before that doesn't have any relation with else.
```